# How to contact a tech company's CERT?

Tags: vulnerability, disclosure

Given I discovered a vulnerability in a product, e.g. a networking product, and can't find the email address of neither their CERT nor a disclosure contact, how should I report the vulnerability? Should I contact the first level tech support and ask for the address? Should I send them a problem description and hope the ticket gets escalated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, I'm making this an answer:

You could either

- contact your countries CERT
- contact the CERT of the manufacturer's country.

Hopefully, they will forward the information appropriately.